# MATLAB declare own data type

Tags: matlab

Like in C, I want to create a own data type, so I have one file declare this type and can later use them as a mask. What I want to do is something like this:

```
function declareParameter()
param1=struct(...
    'argument_a1',[],...
    'argument_a2',[],...
    'argument_a3',[]);

param2=struct(...
    'argument_b1',[],...
    'argument_b2',[]);

param2=struct(...
    'argument_c1',[],...
    'argument_c2',[],...
    'argument_c3',[],...
    'argument_c4',[]);
end
```

so I have param, that I can use as "my self defined data type". Late in my code I only want to write

```
p=param1;
p.argument_a1=....;
o=param2;
o.argument_b2=....;
n=param3;
n.argument_c1=...;
n.argument_c4=...;
```

Is there any possibility to define something like `param` that I can use as my system wide prototype? Doing this in a function, doesn't work, because then the structs are only local variables....

Comment: Matlab support Object Oriented programming, if that is what you mean. Furthermore, since it is dynamically typed you can just do `p.argument1` at any time.

Comment: sure, but I want, that p contains all fileds defined in `param`, even if they are empty (becuase they get filled later or something else). So I can not only use `p.argument1=...`

Comment: Matlab has `struct`'s. You don't even need to declare `p`; just add fields on the fly

Comment: the problem is, that we are a team working on something and I want to have a basic structure for all. Therefore I want define a basic structure, everybody can work with and I must guarantee, that everyone can use a predefined summary of fields of the struct. So add fields on the fly is no good idea...

Comment: If you want the argument list to be always constant (the list, not their value) and protected from users inadvertent deletion or overwriting, making a matlab custom class is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

```
function out = param
out=struct(...
    'argument1',[],...
    'argument2',[],...
    'argument3',[]);
end

>> a = param
a = 
    argument1: []
    argument2: []
    argument3: []
>> b = param
b = 
    argument1: []
    argument2: []
    argument3: []
```

Alternatively you could create a simple object, which might be better if you want to restrict things to only having fields named `argument1`, `argument2`, and `argument3`:

```
classdef param
    properties
        argument1
        argument2
        argument3
    end
end

>> a = param
a = 
  param with properties:

    argument1: []
    argument2: []
    argument3: []
>> b = param
b = 
  param with properties:

    argument1: []
    argument2: []
    argument3: []
```

Comment: at first thanks for your reply, but maybe my question was not well decribed. I want define more tahn one "global" struct, and each having different fields. I will specify my question...